# Synteny, genetics?

Tags: genetics

Could anyone explain the concept of Synteny relating to genetics? A picture would help. I tried read the wikipedia source along with another PDF

http://gep.wustl.edu/repository/course_materials_WU/annotation/About_Synteny_Analysis.pdf

And I feel it only somewhat helped. From what I gather synteny is about the order of genes, relative to their homologous genes? Or their location in general?

Comment: Same relative location i.e order in different chromosomes. Also have a look at [homologous synteny blocks](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2675965/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntenic blocks contain the same genes of order between chromosomes of different species.

[image]

The figure above shows (left to right) syntenic block shared between human chromosome 17 and corresponding chromosomes in three other mammals (horse, pig and chimpanzee). And as expected, the more distinct the species (such as pig and horse) the more disarranged the order of genes are.

Ref: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3758187/

Comment: What do you mean by "the same genes of order"?   Did you mean something like "the same genes, in the same order,"?

Comment: yes same genes, same order.